# Status For Database Synchronization

Tags: mysql, xampp, synchronization

I have 2 database synchronization with each other. Every time I change the database, the other database will be updated automatically .I want to know is there a way to know if the database is synchronized or not synchronized ? Because sometimes when I run the application data from the database is not synchronized

Comment: Are you talking about MySQL replication???

Comment: @AdarshGangadharan Yes